# How to make UITableview exact height?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have following issue
I am having one button on main view if i was click on this button add subview on the main view as tableview 
here is the code

```
FNsettingsViewController *fnsettings = [[FNsettingsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FNsettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
fnsettings.delegate=self;
[fnsettings.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.size.width,250)];
[self.view addSubview:fnsettings.view];
```

after i was click on the button get the subview as tableview but rest of them having an whitespace.

then how to remove the remaining whitespace.

please anyone known help me.

Comment: set `fnsettings.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Answer (score 0):

Before allocate value to the Tableview you will knows the cells count right? the try my code:

```
float height=[arrayTableValues count]*height of your single cell;
tableview.frame=CGRectMake(0,30,self.view.frame.size.width,height);
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi  you can try these one

```
//You can manage the height of a table view using this method.
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{

// Return the height of the row what ever you want Like:below.
return 50;
}
```

Thanks