# How to make UITableview exact height and removing unwanted white space footer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an following issue I am having one button on main view if i was click on this button add subview on the main view as tableview here is the code

```
ViewController *settings = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
settings.delegate=self;
[settings.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.size.width,250)];
[self.view addSubview:settings.view];
```

after i was click on the button get the subview as tableview but rest of them having an whitespace.

then how to remove the remaining whitespace.

[image]

Comment: is it yours ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595467/how-to-make-uitableview-exact-height/21595496#21595496

Comment: What is white space ?? is it tableView or main view ??

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, it looks that you have set wrong height of your ViewController's view i.e., `250`. Make sure the `tableView` inside the view have the `same height` as your are assigning in `setFrame` function here:

```
ViewController *settings = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
settings.delegate=self;
[settings.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.size.width, HeightOfYourTableView)];
[self.view addSubview:settings.view];
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply calculate the height of your table view by multiplying the number of items by the height of the cell, let's say 44 by default.

But regarding the white background, you can do it from the Interface Builder or inside the code like this: (of course I am assuming that inside ViewController, you have access to the table view using some variable)

```
youTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```